# Eclipse undefined reference

Tags: eclipse, mingw

I'm using Eclipse and MinGW. I've got `undefined reference to` error to all that I write in h files, that I do include in cpp-file where main located. I create an empty project, and the same thing again (

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Stack<int> stack(10);
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_

template <class T>
class Stack{
private:
    struct StackEl;
    StackEl *top;
public:
    Stack();
    Stack(T el);
    ~Stack();
    void Push(const T& el);
    T Pop();
};

#endif /* STACK_H_ */
```

and stack.cpp inplements everything from stack.h
If I include not h-file, but cpp - all works. Help please!

I've got following errors

```
D:/Workspacee/Stack2/Debug/../src/Stack2.cpp:16: undefined reference to `Stack<int>::Stack(int)'
D:/Workspacee/Stack2/Debug/../src/Stack2.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Stack<int>::~Stack()'
D:/Workspacee/Stack2/Debug/../src/Stack2.cpp:18: undefined reference to `Stack<int>::~Stack()'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, that is becouse templates! When you use template, all code, including realization of functions, must be in header-file, or you have to write prototypes for every type you are going to use you template-functions with. I've forgot about that working with templates is not the same as with usual function :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a linker error. I'm no Eclipse expert, but you have to tell it somehow to add `Stack.o` to the linking command.
If you include `Stack.cpp` instead of `Stack.h`, the implementations from the cpp-file get included into main.cpp by the preprocessor before compilation, so the linking stage has no unresolved references to outside functions.

Comment: My bad, that is becouse templates! When you use template, all code, including realization of functions, must be in header-file, or you have to write prototypes for every type you are going to use you template-functions with. I've forgot about that working with templates is not the same as with usual function :(